# Getting current, previous and next schedule in Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a schedule table which records schedules of patients. I want to retrieve the current (today's schedule), previous schedule (last time it was scheduled) and next schedule. The structure of Schedule table is like

**Schedule**

```
Id uniqueindentifier
PatientId uniqueindentifier
Start datetime
End datetime
Remarks varchar
```

Current, previous and next will be based on Start column. Start date can be any date (not in continuous).

My approach:

```
db.DbContext.Schedules.Where(i => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(i.Start)  == today && i.PatientId==patientId).Take(1)
    .Union(ctx.DbContext.Schedules.Where(i => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(i.Start) < today && i.PatientId == patientId).OrderByDescending(d => d.Start).Take(1))
    .Union(ctx.DbContext.Schedules.Where(i => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(i.Start) > today && i.PatientId == patientId).OrderBy(d => d.Start).Take(1))
```

I want to know if it is efficient or a better option is available.

Comment: What ORM you using?

Comment: Entity Framework 6.0

Comment: Why do you want to know if there is a better option?  Are you having problems?  Don't fall into [Premature Optimization](http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000084.html).

Answer (score 0):

A better approach will depend on what you will do after with this schedules.

One problem with your solution is you currently don't know which schedule is `Today`, `Previous`, `Next` but perhaps you don't need it either.

If you need to know it, one solution may be using anonymous type instead

```
var schedule = db.DbContext.Schedules.Select(x => new {
    Today = x.Where(i => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(i.Start) == today && i.PatientId==patientId).Take(1),
    Previous = x.Where(i => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(i.Start) < today && i.PatientId == patientId).OrderByDescending(d => d.Start).Take(1),
    Next = x.Where(i => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(i.Start) > today && i.PatientId == patientId).OrderBy(d => d.Start).Take(1)
});
```